# Implementation of message in publish-subscribe pattern?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, publish-subscribe

I'm currently implementing the publish-subscribe pattern for use in my future applications. Right now I'm having trouble figuring out the "best" way to design the message part of the pattern. I have a couple of ideas in mind but please tell me if there's a better way to do it.

**Idea 1:** Each message is an object that implements a simple tag interface IMessage.

**Idea 2:** Each message is represented as an array where the first index is the type of message and the second contains the payload.

Are any of these "better" than the other and if so, why? Please excuse me if this seems like a stupid question.

Comment: Either could work, theoretically (you haven't provided any details like programming language, nature of the data etc.). However, if this is potentially going to be used in a distributed system, you might want to consider using an existing message queue solution such as JMS in Java or ZeroMQ, rather than "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: Sorry about that, the language is C#. This is purely for learning purposes and applications that I fiddle around with on my free time.

The data could be anything really, it can be a command to play music in a game or a message that is sent in a chat application.

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea make more sense, take a look at the [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/NServiceBus) [github](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus) implementation of messaging patterns using marker interfaces or unobtrusive message definitions.

In essence a message in publish/subscribe scenario is an event, it's name should describe the event and have the relevant reference to data related to this event.

[Andreas has a good article](http://andreasohlund.net/2012/02/21/talk-putting-your-events-on-a-diet/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are useful. The first is useful when working with the message in your application. The second is useful if you are receiving raw message data over the network and have to determine how to deserialize it.

If you look at how WCF serializes, then they put the type as an attribute in the serialization, so it knows what to deserialize it to. However if you are going for JSON serialization fx, then you are probably better off having a property to hold your type information. Also be aware that this type information does not have to specify an actual CLR type, just an identifier to let you know how to read the data.

Once you know how to read the data, then you can create your object and take advantage of the type system, ex. using tag interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify whether your messages cross process boundaries or not.

In the latter case, where messages are passed between layers in the same application, the first approach where messages are just objects (optionally implementing the same interface) is probably the easiest.

In the former, where you have interprocess and interoperable messaging, I think you get the most of XML. XML is very flexible, easy to support in different techologies, allows you to sign messages in an interoperable way (XMLDSig) and allows you to create variety of different input/output ports (tcp/http/database/filesystem). Also, messages can be easily validated for their integrity with XSD specifications.

Answer (score 0):

In the pypubsub library (a publish-subscribe for python), I found that there was great benefit to name the payload data, so the sender and receiver can just populate fields and not have to rely on order of items in message, plus it provides "code as documentation". For example, compare these, written in *pseudocode*. Using array:

```
function listener(Object[] message):
   do stuff with message[0], message[1], ...
message = { 123, 'abc', obj1 } // an array
sendMessage('topicName', message)
```

Using keywords:

```
function listener(int radius, string username = None):
   do stuff with radius, username, ...
// username is marked as optional for receiver but we override the default
sendMessage('topicName', radius=123, username='abc')
```

Doing this in C# may be more of a challenge than in Python, but that capability is really useful in pypubsub. Also, you can then use XML to define the schema for your messages, documenting the payload items, and you can mark some payload items as optional (when they have a default value) vs required (when they don't). The lib can also check that the listener adheres to the "payload contract", and that the sender is providing all data promised via the "contract".

You should probably take a look at (and even use) existing libraries to get some ideas (pypubsub is at pypubsub.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are viable, the second one involves that you are responsible for the de/serialization of the message, it gives you much more freedom, power and control over the message, espacially versioning, but all this comes at a cost and I see this cost sustainable only if some of the actors are not .net actors. Otherwise go with the first approach and as Sean pointed out take a look at toolkits and frameworks that can greatly help you with all the plumbing.